# UI / UX concepts should be applied for Small / Medium Sites only?

Tags: readability, advertisement

I reviewed a my client site for better content optimization, SEO optimization, UI/UX optimization etc.

So I suggested many things like changing ad placements, reducing ads to better UI / UX.

But he said that I was wrong because most of the very popular sites using too many ads, etc......

He saw me to lots of site.

Ex : http://www.dailymail.co.uk/sciencetech/article-4747904/Google-receives-FTC-complaint-privacy-issues.html

He is correct because too many ads are on that page and huge time takes to load.

---

He asked me that even very popular sites in the world doesn't have UI / UX experts? He said they follow the best practices... I mean he try to mean that I am bad UI / UX person....

So how do I prove that him to those pages are bad UI/UX wise even their are very popular sites.

Comment: Once your client has built up enough brand loyalty that his customers will tolerate all sorts of hideous practices then maybe he can put adverts everywhere and slow the site down to a crawl. But if this is a new site without any reason for customers to stick around then really you want to be doing things to encourage them to stick around by making things as easy to use as possible.

Comment: I agree with JonW and what I think a lot of people forget is that large known websites do A/B testing constantly. What you see today might be totally different tomorrow, and only they know the results.

Answer (score 1):

Popularity doesn't necessarily mean a good UI/UX. People can visit websites out of habit and necessity. For example, I work in UX optimisation for a company that owns many different eCommerce sites - none of them are particularly amazing or follow a lot of the common UX principles but you'd be surprised at the traffic and conversion rate.

I'd suggest looking around the web for sites you know have huge traffic volumes yet aren't following conventional UX and compile a list to show him, real world examples are always a great way to explain situations to a stakeholder.

On a side note... why has this guy asked you to review their site to just then shut down your professional opinion? Seems a bit backward.